# How do I correctly format this 1 line of Excel VBA code to filter out duplicates?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a line of code that was working until I made one little adjustment.  The problem is that I don't understand why my adjustment throws out the error: Run time error 1004, this command requires at least two rows of source data....

Working line of code:

```
Range("E1", Range("E65536").End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("J1"), Unique:=True
```

Broken code: (LastRow is a long variable)

```
Range("E1", Range("E" & LastRow).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("J1"), Unique:=True
```

Comment: I don't know much about VBA, but does LastRow have to be explicitly converted to a string?  Maybe concatenating it implicitly changes its value somehow?  I'm not sure.

Comment: I converted the long variable, LastRow, into a CString but it still throws out the same error.  This is the line of code: Range("E1", Range("E" & CStr(LastRow)).End(xlUp)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("J1"), Unique:=True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Range("E1", "E" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("J1"), Unique:=True`.

It seemed like you were using `.End(xlUp)` when you were already referencing the last row.

Comment: You are right.  But, now I realize there's something else I don't understand and would like to fix that.  Exactly what does the code Range("E65536").End(xlUp)) do?  Does it mean, find the last row of data used in Column E no matter if it is beyond Row 65536 or before Row 65536?

Comment: Nothing will be beyond Row 65536 (I believe that's the current max row option in Excel), so yes, you are right--it starts at the end and looks up until it finds the last piece of data.  xlDown works similarly, only it looks down.  Some people use xlUp to find the last row of data because xlDown might get confused if there are blank rows and then more data after those blank rows.

Comment: the max row is 65,535 in 2003 and before, 1,048,576 in 2007 and after

Answer (score 2):

I can't for the life of me find the comment link, so I apologize this isn't a comment.  I believe Excel uses that xlUp to find the last row of data (and not get all the blank rows between the last row of data and the actual last row--65536).  In your adjustment, it seems like you're already starting at or know the last row, so I'm not sure you need to use the xlUp.  I think in the second example you could take out ".End(xlUp)".  Would that work?  And in that case, you could also shorten the reference to:

```
Range("E1:E" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter...
```

Let me know if that helps or if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: You are correct to rryanp, but vergenzt answered first and beat you to it.  I upvoted your answer though.

Answer (score 2):

On a fake dataset I generated, I get the error with both examples of your code. What I've found to sometimes be a useful trick when trying to figure out what ranges are getting selected is to use the activate method.

Try this

```
Range("E1", Range("E65536").End(xlUp)).Activate
```

and see what gets selected. I don't know what your data looks like, and I'm not quite sure what range you're trying to select, but I'd guess that cell E65536 is actually empty, so Range("E65536").End(xlUp) is effectively the same as Range("E1").End(xlDown). Since your code is working, I'd assume that what gets selected will be a range with multiple rows.

Next try...

```
Range("E1", Range("E" & LastRow).End(xlUp)).Activate
```

and look at your workbook to see what gets selected. I'm not sure how you're defining LastRow without seeing all your code, but I'd bet that what gets selected is just a single cell. Frankly, I think the best solution (if indeed you want to start at E1 and grab all the rows down until they're empty) is to do this:

```
Range("E1", Range("E1").End(xlDown)).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("J1"), Unique:=True
```

If this isn't what you want, clarify what sort of range you want, and maybe we can give you something better to work with. Good luck!

Comment: Daniel, this is extremely helpful for me..being able to SEE what is getting selected.  Upvote!

Comment: Glad it's helpful. It was a huge boon to me when I was doing a lot of work with VBA.